# Teamcity web deploy to Web Management Service with site query string

Tags: azure, deployment, teamcity, webdeploy

I am trying to setup a Teamcity web deploy script to deploy to an Azure environment using the WMSvc calling an endpoint with a site query string. Teamcity web deploy breaks when I try to set a query string in my /M: parameter. My command parameters look like this:

```
/Y /M:%WebDeploy.ComputerName%MSDeploy.axd?site=%system.SPDestination% /U:%WebDeploy.UserName% /P:%WebDeploy.Password% /A:%WebDeploy.AuthType% –allowUntrusted -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule
```

I tried to use encoding on the equals sign %96 but this will create a new parameter in the build parameter. Using double percentage signs (%%96) to escape this will remove the build parameter but the encoding won't get decoded to the equals sign.

I tried to place the whole parameter between quotes in multiple ways but this doesn't have the preferred result. Also tried to put the value in between quotes.

```
'"/M:%WebDeploy.ComputerName%/MSDeploy.axd?site=%system.SPDestination%"'
'/M:%WebDeploy.ComputerName%/MSDeploy.axd?site=%system.SPDestination%'
"/M:%WebDeploy.ComputerName%/MSDeploy.axd?site%system.SPDestination%"
/M:'%WebDeploy.ComputerName%/MSDeploy.axd?site%system.SPDestination%'
/M:'"%WebDeploy.ComputerName%/MSDeploy.axd?site%system.SPDestination%"'
```

If this is possible what do I need to do to get this to work?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was caused by Teamcity. We used the build configuration for a different project and it worked fine. Something in Teamcity went wrong during the creation of the build configuration for the project. We still don't know what caused it, but it seems that it is a rare situation and probably won't happen again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
/M:"%WebDeploy.ComputerName%/MSDeploy.axd?site=%system.SPDestination%"
```

Comment: Does not seem to work I am getting an error:
Unmatched quote in the executable path

I am placing double quotes on the beginning and the end of the value.

Comment: So the complete value specified in the command parameters is:

/Y /M:"%WebDeploy.ComputerName%/MSDeploy.axd?site=%system.SPDestination%" /U:%WebDeploy.UserName% /P:%WebDeploy.Password% /A:%WebDeploy.AuthType%
 –allowUntrusted  -verbose -debug -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension

Comment: I am using Teamcity 8.0.6

Comment: I'm thinking the command itself may be wrong and not the params.